# asp.net send mail problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I try to send email from my application. Everything  seems ok, mailmessage, credentials etc.

When I debug the code it doesnt fall in to catch exception and doesnt send email. Also there is no mail queue at the server.There is no error message.

```
msgObj.Subject = this.Subject;        
    msgObj.From = new MailAddress(this.From , this.Display_Name);//
    msgObj.Body = this.Message;
    msgObj.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(this.SMTP_Server,25);
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_User + "@doping.com.tr", SMTP_Password);


                try
                {
                    client.Send(msgObj);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.ToString();
                    return false;
                }
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything helpful in the application event log?

Comment: Also do check if the to-address/from-address contains a valid email id. Certain mail servers perform may not perform validation on these, so send might be successful, but the mail would still not reach the recipient.
    If this still does not work, try using the System.Net.Mail namespace instead of the System.Web.Mail as the latter has been marked obselete.

Comment: there is no error at application event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default settings of an `SmtpClient` can be configured using the `System.Net` configuration namespace, e.g:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="ben@contoso.com">
        <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

See the [<smtp> Element (Network Settings) topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check for port. Is port 25 you are using support. Also check for SSL. If still not works. Try below code.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Transmit an email message
/// </summary>
/// <param name="from">Senders Name </param>
/// <param name="fromPerson">Sender Email Address</param>
/// <param name="body">The Email Message Body</param>
/// <returns>Status Message as String</returns>
public static void SendMail(string fromEmail, string fromName, string body)
{

    try
    {

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);
            mail.Subject = "Report ";
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = global::ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.Host;
            smtp.Port = global::ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.Port;

            if (smtp.Port == 587)
            {
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            }
            string userName = global::ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
            string password = global::ProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            smtp.Send(mail);

        }
    }

    catch (SmtpException smEx)
    {
        LogError(smEx.Message, smEx.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Here I am using Settings file of the project and retrieving values from there.